# How to use a T420 with two external displays?

Tags: 12.04

Using an Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS on a notebook on the table there are two displays (Lenovo L2240P) connected to a Thinkpad T420:

Left display: connected with DVI.

Right display: connected with VGA.

They look like this when all is connected:

```
USER@NOTEBOOK:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3280 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+69 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+   74.9  
   1600x1000      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

lspci:

```
USER@NOTEBOOK:~$ lspci -v
...
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 21d0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
...
```

**Purpose:** We don't need the screen of the notebook, only the screen on the two monitors (not in clone mode!)

**Q:** How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Lenovo's own support forums](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/T400-T500-and-newer-T-series/t420-dual-external-monitors/td-p/820793) suggest that you need the dock for this:

> It worked, I have experienced it with my own eyes. 2560x1600 on both 30 inch monitors using one Displayport on the mini series 3 docking station and one Displayport on the side of the laptop.

Though I can't guarantee this all works with Ubuntu but at the same time, I can't see why it wouldn't. The dock appears to short-out the built-in screen.

Comment: we tried with a Dock, it didn't worked.